# Display a notification once only after reaching a goal

Tags: android, notifications

I am displaying a notification when user reaches a goal(84KM of walking).I am displaying this notification but when i re-open the app it is being displayed again.How can i do it to run only one time(once the user reaches 84KM)?

Here is the code that i'm checking the KM(in **asynctask**)

```
protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {

        totalKm = (int) Float.parseFloat(TripsInfo.km.get(TripsInfo.userRank - 1));


        if (totalKm == 84 ) {
            milestoneNotification(totalKm);


        } else if (totalKm == 130 ) {
            milestoneNotification(totalKm);

        } else if (totalKm == 200) {
            milestoneNotification(totalKm);

        }

        return null;
    }
```

and one other function to create the notification

```
public void milestoneNotification(int km_up) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Profile.this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.icon_app)
            .setContentTitle("Gekon")
            .setContentText("Congratulations!You reached " + km_up + "KM!")
            .setVibrate((new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000}))
            .setLights(Color.GREEN, 3000, 3000)
            .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(), 0))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

    // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
    notificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

}
```

Comment: Show where you run the async task

Comment: @MaksimNovikov  i call my async task from onCreate();

Comment: try to debug and see in which of the cases you code go.